# Are the words "snarky" and "smarmy" a form of visual onamatopoeia?

Tags: meaning, grammar

I found these two common English words (snarky and smarmy) that seem like forms of a literary device. However, unlike onamatopoeia, the comparison is not made with sound, but rather it is more from the "visual" images/memory that they evoke. What is this called in terms of "literary technique" (if not onamatopoeia)? "Synesthesia" perhaps?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147026/discussion-on-question-by-user22542-are-the-words-snarky-and-smarmy-a-form-o); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we work from the definition given by  Ullman, S. 1962. “Semantics: An Introduction to the Science of Meaning.” Oxford: Basil Blackwell , we have

> 1.**Primary Onomatopoeia** The primary onomatopoeia is the imitation of sound by sound. The sound is produced by the object itself.
>
> 2.**Secondary Onomatopoeia** The secondary onomatopoeia is the sound that occurs because of the relation between the sound of an object and its movement (dither, dodder, quiver, slink, slither, slouch, squirm, and wriggle) or based on the movement only. This onomatopoeia derives from actions.

A glance at the meaning and etymology of **smarm** will put it into Secondary Onomatopoeia as to smarm = to spread an oily substance upon something.

OED

> To smarm is of unknown origin. It was first recorded as
>
> colloquial (originally dialect)
>
> 1.a. dialect. To smear, bedaub.
>
> 1847   J. O. Halliwell Dict. Archaic & Provinc. Words II   Smawm, to smear. Dorset.

And developed to

> 2.a. intransitive. To behave in a fulsomely flattering or toadying manner, to suck up to a person. Also with about, over.
>
> 1911   O. Onions Widdershins ix. 265   It had been the usual thing..twenty years ago—smarming about Art and the Arts.

And then

> **smear**, v.
>
> **Etymology**: Common Germanic: Old English smir-, smyr-, smerian (also smir- , smerwan ), < smeoru, smeru smear n.,

which originally referred to annointing with oil -> spreading something greasy -> and then developed a pejorative meaning.

Using the above and commonly available references, you can make your own decision about the other words.

Comment: Un-commonly helpful

Comment: "the sound that occurs because of the relation between the sound of an object and its movement "  — Say what??

Answer (score 1):

There is no strong evidence that they are onomatopeia. However, there are hypotheses, like those of Etymonline. About ***[snarky](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=snarky&utm_source=extension_s)*** it says:

> "irritable, short-tempered," 1906, from *snark* (v.) "to find fault with, nag" (1882), *literally "to snort" (1866)*, ***which is from an imitative source***. Compare Low German *snarken*, North Frisian *snarke*, Swedish *snarka*; also compare *snarl* (v.2) and *sneer* (v.). Also compare *narky* "bad-tempered, sarcastic" (1895), British slang from earlier *nark* "annoying, quarrelsome, or unpleasant person" (1846), from *nark* (q.v.).

So, *snark* probably imitated snorting, in which case yes, it is an onomatopeia. But I would assume ***snark*** and ***shark*** are coincidental paronyms at best, and not related etymology-wise.

---

About ***[smarm](https://www.etymonline.com/word/smarm?ref=etymonline_crossreference)*** (from which *smarmy* comes), Etymonline makes the following hypothesis:

> 1914, from colloquial verb *smalm*, *smarm* "to smear, bedaub" (the hair, with pomade), 1847, of unknown origin, ***perhaps somehow suggestive of the action.***

So it may imitate the action of smearing, and that's where I am guessing what you mean by *visual onomatopeia*. However, no connection with marmalade is made. Yes, you can smear with marmalade, but since marmalade is not among the *[most common nouns to collocate with smear](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=smeared%20with%20*_NOUN&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)*, I doubt *smarm* can be considered as a combination of smear and marmalade.

Comment: Perhaps, but somehow there seems to be more to it (in terms of the connections they evoke in me). I don't want to get into a bunch of academic theory either. These two words DID coincidently find themselves in the same "article" by way of comparison. What about any other examples/similar words? What about that I feel this is a fair analogy to onamatopoeia? Perhaps there SHOULD be a separate word for this as a literary technique? Those questions still occur to me.

Comment: In that case, you are fringing the realm of _opinion-based_ I am afraid.

Comment: That's your opinion. Please allow time for others to answer.